# How to get a VALUE of an INSERT INTO -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE function into a SELECT?

Tags: mysql

i have setup a DB and what i want is the following:

In Table a i got the users with infos and his points
In Table b i got more infos about each user and his "level"
in Table c i got basic settings
in Table d i got detailed infos about the levels each user can have

What i would like to do is:
 
either INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or IF EXISTS UPDATE (insert would be my fav)
I would like to do the query with multiple users at once (by their id)

The problem right now is how do i get the VALUE into the SELECT Statement ?

My Code so far:

```
INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES ('12345')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE                   
points = (points + (
SELECT (d.multiplier * c.base_points)
FROM b
INNER JOIN d ON b.level = d.id , c
WHERE b.level = d.id AND b.id = '12345'));
```

i now want to change:

```
WHERE
b.level = d.id AND
b.id = '12345'));
```

so that i can use VALUES(id) - but when i do that i get NULL as result

```
WHERE
b.level = d.id AND
b.id = VALUES(id)));
```

:(
How can i use the id i have ?

regards

Comment: You want to insert the same id multiple times, and update the info for that id accordingly? Doesn't look like the right way, to me... Why not use updates?

Comment: the id is the primary key, so if the insert fails, it should do the update, and i only want to update the points of the user if he exists @Cynical

Comment: Ok, but why aren't you using UPDATE instead of INSERT to perform an update operation?